# Having trouble decoding JSON file from Github api swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am trying to decode a JSON format from GitHub API. The url to the api is correct, it returns all values, but JSONdecoder can't read them. Please help, what am I doing wrong?
I have already done JSONDecoder for github api before, but I only needed the username and repository list, but now I need details about a specific repository

There is my func do decode JSON:

```
func getMoreInfo() -> MoreInfo {
        var moreInfo = MoreInfo(name: "", moreInfoDescription: "", contributorsURL: "", stargazersCount: 0, language: "", forksCount: 0, license: License(key: "", name: ""), topics: [])
        
        if let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/repos/allegro/typescript-strict-plugin"){
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responde, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        moreInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(MoreInfo.self, from: data)
                    } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        return moreInfo
    }
```

There are my structs:

```
    let name, moreInfoDescription: String
    let contributorsURL: String
    let stargazersCount: Int
    let language: String
    let forksCount: Int
    let license: License
    let topics: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case moreInfoDescription = "description"
        case contributorsURL = "contributors_url"
        case stargazersCount = "stargazers_count"
        case language
        case forksCount = "forks_count"
        case license, topics
    }
}

struct License: Codable {
    let key: String
    let name: String
}
```

There is the JSON format that gets returned from GitHub API: https://api.github.com/repos/allegro/typescript-strict-plugin

Please tell me what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: `print(error)` Does this print something? Also, could you certify that the response is correct: `print("Response from API: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)")`? And `return moreInfo` wont work, because you are missing the asynchrone concept: add `print("Inside closure: \(moreInfo)")` JUST after `moreInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(MoreInfo.self, from: data)`, and one JUST before `return moreInfo`: `print("Outside closure: \(moreInfo)")`and see which one is printed first and if it has the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well for me, `MoreInfo` is decoded as required.
Using macos 12.2 Beta, Xcode 13.2,
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real devices.

You of course need to deal with the asynchronous function, as @Larme mentioned.
Try this approach:

```
func getMoreInfo(completion: @escaping(MoreInfo?) -> ()) {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/repos/allegro/typescript-strict-plugin"){
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responde, error in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let moreInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(MoreInfo.self, from: data)
                    completion(moreInfo)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                    completion(nil) // todo deal with errors
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

and use it like this:

    getMoreInfo() { info in
        print("\n-------> info: \(info)")
    }
```